# In CKEditor 4.x is there a way to get the list of allowed tags after initialization?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to get a list of all allowed tags in CKEDitor 4.x (4.4.7 to be precise) **after** the editor has been initialized with all plugins, and all `allowedContentRules` and `disallowedContentRules` or any other datafilters have been applied?

I would like to have this list so that I can pass it on to our back-end for whitelisting. I know there is already a whitelist plugin for CKEditor which would allow me to specify the same whitelist on both front-end and back-end, but I'm afraid I may miss some tag used in some plugin which may cripple them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably [`CKEDITOR.filter.allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-property-allowedContent) is what you're looking for. It can be accessed from the `editor.filter` property. Small example of how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/Comandeer/tb6f0g8r/

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function( evt ) {
            // It returns the array of all rules,
            //so if you want to send it to the server,
            // you'll probably need to "JSON-ify" it.
            var allowedContent = evt.editor.filter.allowedContent;
            console.log( JSON.stringify( allowedContent, null, '\t' ) );
        }
    }
} );
```

Maybe that format is not as friendly as simple string, but it conveys all information you need.