# What are the default CKEditor ACF allowed content rules?

Tags: ckeditor

There's documentation about how to set the Advanced Content Filter's [extra allowed content rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) and how to set [disallowed content rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) but what are the allowed content rules by default?

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your configuration. By default, ACF works in automatic mode. It means that out-of-the-box CKEditor will only allow content that was *defined as allowed by enabled editor features* (buttons, plugins, commands).

You can check the [`CKEDITOR.filter.allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-property-allowedContent) property to see which tags are allowed in your instance. See the answer here:

[In CKEditor 4.x is there a way to get the list of allowed tags after initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844420/in-ckeditor-4-x-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-list-of-allowed-tags-after-initializat/35866002#35866002)