# Ckeditor 4.5.7 strips HTML tags despite config.allowedContent = true

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor 4.5.7 and I want the user to insert arbitrary HTML code into the page. For now the users cannot even insert tags like `<h3>test</h3>` - the `<h3>` tags are automatically converted to `<p>` after the data is saved (this is occurring in a SharePoint page).

As per docs here - http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent - and multiple topics here on StackOverflow, I have set this option in config.js to disable content filtering but it seems it has no effect:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

I also tried listing specific tags in this option, as well as in config.extraAllowedContent, but none of it seems to have any effect. Any tags like `<h1>` are stripped anyway.

What else could I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was to check the `CKEDITOR.filter.disallowedContentRules`. As [noted here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disallowedContent), "They have precedence over allowed content rules." However, the [Disallowed Content Guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) notes: "It is not possible to disallow content when the Advanced Content Filter is disabled by setting CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent to `true`."

Without knowing more about your config, my recommendation is to use [Comandeer's jsfiddle for discovering what your allowed content is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866002/7038301).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was on the SharePoint side. It was SharePoint that was stripping the HTML tags.

The multi-line text field that contained CKEditor had this property:

```
textfield.SPRichTextMode = SPRichTextMode.Compatible;
```

After removing this line it worked.