# Ckeditor stripping "html" and "body" tags

Tags: ckeditor4.x

We are using Ckeditor from long time, it is great wysiwyg editor
I set ckeditor version:"4.4.7" for setting up my email templates content.
My issue is as described below

Some of my email templates contain html and body tags , and some inherits common header and footer from other source, so what I am in need of is disable stripping my any input I enter.

I used `allowedContent : true` option but it does not work with html and body tags.

I also used `fullPage : true` , issue with this option is it always add html head title and body section, I do not need this always, in same email templates, sometimes I need , sometimes not.

In short what I need is to stop ckeditor changing my any single character what I type.

Used fullPage : true, but always I do not need html title head and body tags, but If I type, it should be there otherwise not.

`CKEDITOR.replace('myeditor',{
    allowedContent : true,
    fullPage : true
});`

I expect to stop ckeditor changing my any html, even I dont want automated html and body tags when I switch to source using "fullPage:true"

Comment: Is this the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078356/ckeditor-4-5-7-strips-html-tags-despite-config-allowedcontent-true

Comment: Similar, When I am entering html and body, it does not persist, thay are stripped or changed (body to p tag)